# Accessing pods in my EKS worker nodes deployed in private subnet using an Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster that has a node group with 3 worker nodes. This node group is in a private subnet. I have deployed a pod in one of these worker nodes. I was able to access it using port forwarding. Now, my problem is that I want to access these pods using a Application Load Balancer.

I have a VPC with 3 public and 3 private subnet with the public subnets associated to a route table that routes traffic to the Internet Gateway and the private subnets associated to a route table that routes traffic to the NAT Gateway.

I tried creating a service and Ingress with path based routing but when I tried accessing it, it didn't work. I was able to access it when I tried deploying in a separate node group that is in the public subnet. I am new to Kubernetes so please give an easy to follow solution.

Thanks :)